# C-loops and goto

Tags: c, goto

How can i remove the **goto** from the following code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool is_prime(unsigned num)
{

   if(num==0 || num==1)
     return false;
   if(num==2)
     return true;
   for(unsigned i=2;i<=num-1;i++)
    if(num%i==0)
        goto step;

             return true;
      step:  return false;
}


int main(void)
{
  unsigned n;
  printf("enter the number: ");
  scanf("%u",&n);
  printf("%u\n",is_prime(n));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, I've seen some code in my time, but that was a first!

Comment: return (num < 2); instead of that first if would be nice as well.

Comment: Considering your current method to solve the problem one suggestion would be not to iterate over even numbers. Check once with 2 then move over to odd numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with `return false;`. `return` exits a function. The code even relies on that behaviour already.

```
bool is_prime(unsigned num)
{
    if(num == 0 || num == 1)
        return false;
    for(int i = 2; i < num - 1; i++)
        if(num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I was just one step away.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `goto` statement and use `return false` instead.

```
   if(num%i==0)
       // goto step;
       return false;

   return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(num%i==0)    //if true return false and if fail return true.
    goto step;   

         return true;
  step:  return false;
```

above block is equal to

```
    if(num%i==0)    //if true return false and if fail return true.
       return false;   
     return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

um three ways

```
if(num%i!=0)
       return false;
return true;
```

Or you could use an `else`.

Or you could just do

```
return (num%i == 0);
```